# ELK: start logstash fails, illegalstateexception

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Since my server could not access internet. I downloaded filebeat, logstash, elasticsearch and kibana's rpm format files.

I use command `rpm -Uvh xxx.rpm` to install `filebeat logstash elasticsearch and kibana`. Then I modified configuration. For logstash, I updated `pipelines.yml` and copy it to `/etc/logstash/conf.d` directory.

The piplelines.yml is as follows:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => "5044"
    }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => [
                "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{DATA:threadname}\] - %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} - app-info-exception-info - params:%{SPACE}\{\"%{DATA:jsondata}\"\} %{DATA:excentionname}: %{DATA:exceptiondetail}\n(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:extralines}",
                "(?<timestamp>[\d\-\s\:]+)\s\[(?<threadname>[\d\.\w\s\(\)\-]+)\]\s-\s(?<loglevel>[\w]+)\s+-\s(?<appinfo>app-info)\s-\s(?<systemmsg>[\w\d\:\{\}\,\-\(\)\s\"]+)",
                "(?<timestamp>[\d\-\s\:]+)\s\[(?<threadname>[\d\.\w\s\(\)\-]+)\]\s-\s(?<loglevel>[\w]+)\s+-\s+(?<systemmsg>[\s\.\w\-\'\:\d\[\]\/]+)"
                        ]
        }
  }
}
output {
  #stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    index => "ykt"
  }
}
```

From /var/log/, I could see filebeat, elasticsearch are fine. But in logstash's logstash-plain.log, there are error messages:

```
[2018-06-20T20:21:54,138][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
[2018-06-20T20:22:07,642][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
[2018-06-20T20:22:21,299][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
[2018-06-20T20:22:34,572][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
[2018-06-20T20:22:48,019][ERROR][org.logstash.Logstash    ] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
```

After updation yml/configuration, I do

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart logstash
```

I do not why there is illegalStateException. Any help?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: filebeat, logstash, kibana and elasticsearch's version are all 6.3.0.

Comment: CentOS 7.4 is the hardware.